# Dictionaries in loop

Tags: python

```
duck_1 = {
    "first_name": "Davey",
    "followers": 12865,
    "following": 120,
    "weapons": ["wit", "steely stare", "devilish good looks"]
}
duck_2 = {
    "first_name": "Jim",
    "followers": 123,
    "following": 5000,
    "weapons": ["squeak"]
}
duck_3 = {
    "first_name": "Celest",
    "followers": 40189,
    "following": 1, 
    "weapons": ["politics", "dance moves", "chess grandmaster", "immortality"]
}

duck_collection = [ duck_1, duck_2, duck_3 ]

for duck in duck_collection:
        duck1=(duck_1['followers']-duck_1['following'])
        print(duck1)
        duck2=(duck_2['followers']-duck_2['following'])
        print(duck2)
        duck3=(duck_3['followers']-duck_3['following'])
```

the output is:

```
12745
-4877
40188
12745
-4877
40188
12745
-4877
40188
```

i want the output to be:

```
12745
-4877
40188
```

and also result should be append to Trendy Ducks: [12745, -4877, 40188]

Comment: Notice how you are doing the same calculation on 3 different dictionaries. The point of the loop is so you only have to write the calculation once but the code will still repeat it 3 times, once for each item in the list.

Comment: I edited the title since you only have one loop, not "nested" loops.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
trendyDucks = [duck['followers'] - duck['following'] for duck in duck_collection]
print(trendyDucks)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know list comprehension you could use just this:

```
trendyDucks = []    
for duck in duck_collection:
        trendyDucks.append(duck['followers']-duck['following'])
```